# XLSXWriter: Add Hyperlink to Image?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'd like to add a hyperlink to an image using XLSXWriter. However, the XLSXWriter docs at:

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images.html

...make no mention of hyperlinks.

Is there a way to add a hyperlink to an image via XLSXWriter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to add a hyperlink to an image via XLSXWriter?

Yes. See the docs on [insert_image()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#insert_image):

*The `url` parameter can used to add a hyperlink/url to the image...:*

```py
worksheet.insert_image('B4', 'python.png', {'url': 'https://python.org'})
```